# Hibernate only saving 2 of 3 values in database

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, struts2, null

i am trying to create an entity called muziekstuk with entitys called instrument and componist
So i created a join-table with 3 Foreign keys to the id's of muziekstuk instrument and componist.

muziekstuk and instrument are created and componist i select from a dropdown

this is the action code:

```
    MuziekstukDAOImpl reg = new MuziekstukDAOImpl();
    ComponistDAOImpl com = new ComponistDAOImpl();

    int componistid = Integer.parseInt(MComponist);
    Componist componist = (Componist) com.getById(componistid);

    Instrument i1 = new Instrument(MInstrument1, Integer.parseInt(MAantal1));

    Muziekstuk muziekstuk = new Muziekstuk(MTitel,MGenre,componist,i1);
    reg.save(muziekstuk);
```

it does make an new instrument and muziekstuk only in the join table the id of componist is null :S
anyone know why?

Here is the rest of my code:
Muziekstuk:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUD1630651.MFMUZIEKSTUK")
public class Muziekstuk {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE_MUZIEKSTUK")
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "TITEL")
private String titel;

@Column(name = "GENRE")
private String genre;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinTable(name="MFMUZIEKSTUKJOIN",joinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="MUZIEKSTUKID")},inverseJoinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="COMPONISTID")})
private Componist componist;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinTable(name="MFMUZIEKSTUKJOIN",joinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="MUZIEKSTUKID")},inverseJoinColumns=
{@JoinColumn(name="INSTRUMENTID")})
private Instrument instrument;


public Muziekstuk(String titel, String genre, Componist componist, Instrument instrument){
    this.titel = titel;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.componist = componist;
    this.instrument = instrument;
}

public Muziekstuk(int id, String titel, String genre, Componist componist, Instrument instrument){
    this.id = id;
    this.titel = titel;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.componist = componist;
    this.instrument = instrument;
}


//GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

Componist:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUD1630651.MFCOMPONIST")  
public class Componist {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE_COMPONIST")
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "NAAM")  
private String naam;

@Column(name = "LAND")  
private String land;

@Column(name = "TIJDVLAK")
private String tijdvlak;

@Column(name = "COMPOSITIES")
private String composities;


public Componist(int id, String naam, String land, String tijdvlak, String composities){
    this.id = id;
    this.naam = naam;
    this.land = land;
    this.tijdvlak = tijdvlak;
    this.composities = composities;
}

public Componist(String naam, String land, String tijdvlak, String composities){
    this.naam = naam;
    this.land = land;
    this.tijdvlak = tijdvlak;
    this.composities = composities;
}

public Componist(){
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

Instrument:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUD1630651.MFCOMPONIST")  
public class Componist {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE_COMPONIST")
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "NAAM")  
private String naam;

@Column(name = "LAND")  
private String land;

@Column(name = "TIJDVLAK")
private String tijdvlak;

@Column(name = "COMPOSITIES")
private String composities;


public Componist(int id, String naam, String land, String tijdvlak, String composities){
    this.id = id;
    this.naam = naam;
    this.land = land;
    this.tijdvlak = tijdvlak;
    this.composities = composities;
}

public Componist(String naam, String land, String tijdvlak, String composities){
    this.naam = naam;
    this.land = land;
    this.tijdvlak = tijdvlak;
    this.composities = composities;
}

public Componist(){
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

save function in the DAO:

```
@Override
public void save(Object t) {
  Muziekstuk muziekstuk = (Muziekstuk) t;
  System.out.println(muziekstuk.getComponist().getId());
  Session session = null;  
  Transaction transaction = null;  
  try {  
      session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  
      transaction = session.beginTransaction(); 
      session.saveOrUpdate(muziekstuk);
      transaction.commit();   
  } catch (Exception e) {  
      if (transaction != null) {  
          transaction.rollback();
          System.out.println("exception");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }  
  } finally {  
      if (session != null) {  
          session.close();  
      }  
  }  

}
```

This is the sql trace:

```
Hibernate: select componist0_.ID as ID1_2_0_, componist0_.COMPOSITIES as COMPOSIT2_2_0_, componist0_.LAND as       LAND3_2_0_, componist0_.NAAM as NAAM4_2_0_, componist0_.TIJDVLAK as TIJDVLAK5_2_0_ from STUD1630651.MFCOMPONIST componist0_ where componist0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE_MUZIEKSTUK.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE_INSTRUMENT.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into STUD1630651.MFINSTRUMENT (HOEVEELHEID, NAAM, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUD1630651.MFMUZIEKSTUK (GENRE, TITEL, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into MFMUZIEKSTUKJOIN (INSTRUMENTID, MUZIEKSTUKID) values (?, ?)
```

Ther should be 3 ? in MUZIEKSTUKJOIN

Comment: It turns out a join table can only refer to 1 table not 2 so you should make 2 join tables if someone is wondering.

Comment: Please post your comment as your answer and accept it, so that someone with similar issue can get help out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a join table can only refer to 1 table not 2 so you should make 2 join tables if someone is wondering.